# How to get id value in protractor and use in if condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, protractor

In my project i have code:

```
<div class="slotMachineContainer" style="margin-top: -156px;">
    <div ng-repeat="game in GameModel" class="start-game-block-text ng-binding ng-scope" id="round_1_3">Speed Sort</div>
    <div ng-repeat="game in GameModel" class="start-game-block-text ng-binding ng-scope" id="round_1_0"></div>
    <div ng-repeat="game in GameModel" class="start-game-block-text ng-binding ng-scope" id="round_1_1">Rapid Fill-In-The-Blank</div>
    <div ng-repeat="game in GameModel" class="start-game-block-text ng-binding ng-scope" id="round_1_2">Lightning Swipe</div>
    <div ng-repeat="game in GameModel" class="start-game-block-text ng-binding ng-scope" id="round_1_3">Speed Sort</div>
    <div ng-repeat="game in GameModel" class="start-game-block-text ng-binding ng-scope" id="round_1_0"></div>
</div>
```

This implemented  randomization.
My question is how that sets the value of the variable id e.g. # round_1_3 or string between div tags `<div>Speed Sort</div>` may also examine if the condition of these random back me that I can use to do protractor test. I tried `var element = (by.id ('# random_1_3')).getText ();` but didn't work.
If you have any suggestions to help me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are already various locators that you can use for protractor. Simplest one for your case would be to use `by.id`. However your syntax looks wrong to me. Also in protractor everything returns a promise. So in order for you to use it, you should wait for the promise to return and then console log it. Here's a sample of it -

```
element(by.id('random_1_3')).getText().then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
});
```

[More on Protractor locators](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy). Hope this helps.